# How to interpret Tortoise Git Revision Graph?

Tags: git

I have a very small development effort as shown in the attached revision graph.  At the top (end) of the graph are three branches (master FrontDist, and DRV8871), but they are all in the same block.

I have used the 'browse references' utility to compare 'master' with each of the other branches, and TG tells me there were no differences found.  I know in the past I have merged development branches back into 'master', but I've never subsequently looked at the revision graph.  Is this depiction trying to tell me that both 'FrontDist' and 'DRV8871' have already been merged back into 'master' but I currently have the 'FrontDist' branch checked out?

TIA,

Frank
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Those three branches are referencing the same commit.

If there was any merge, it was from the "fast-forward" variety: the merged branch simply moved its HEAD, since there is no commit with *two* parent (actual merge)

You can see in [TortoiseGit Colour Settings 2](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-colours2) that:

- green means "local branch"
- red means "current branch"

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/SettingsColors2.png]

Comment: Is there any option to show all commits in the revision graph?

Comment: @Ini possibly, according to https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html: In the lower left there are the checkboxes All branches and Show whole project. Use these to override the branch resp. a file/folder filter and show the log for the whole repository.

Comment: But this is in "show log" and not the revision graph. And how do I know which color represents which branch name in the log?

Comment: @Ini on the colors: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-colours3. And the "Show log" does include the "revision graph" column: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html#tgit-dug-showlog-graph

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - answered my own question.  I created a new branch from 'master', made some trivial comment changes, and then committed the new branch.  Now the revision graph shows all three of the previous branches (DRV8871, FrontDist, and master) all in the same green block, with 'FindParallel' (the new branch) in red at the top.

Frank
[image]

Comment: So did I answered your question?